# How to join two strings one of which is Subscript?

Tags: string-manipulation

If I write this one

```
str=Subscript["x","y"];
StringQ[str]
```

> False

How can I get `str` as string?

Comment: `StringQ` asked whether str was a string. Mathematica correctly answered, "False".  Try `str//FullForm` or str//FreeForm to confirm the structure of str.  Then try ToString[str] and see what you get.

Comment: @DavidCarraher, I have tried ToString[str] . But that gives undesirable result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ToString[Subscript["x", "y"], FormatType -> StandardForm]
```

[image]

```
StringQ[%]
```

> True

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Equivalently and shorter: `ToString[Subscript["x", "y"], StandardForm]`

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica version 10, `StringTemplate` can allow you to convert to string, e.g.

```
st = StringTemplate[
   "Pythagoras theorem: \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(`1`\), \
\(2\)]\)+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(`2`\), \(2\)]\)= \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(`3`\), \(2\)]\)"];
```

You can apply the template and yield a string,, allowing you to style, join etc.

```
TemplateApply[st, {x, y, z}]
```

yields:

[image]

`StringQ@TemplateApply[st, {x, y, z}]` yields `True`

and to illustrate `StringJoin` and `Style`:

```
Style[TemplateApply[st, {x, y, z}] <> ". QED", Red, 
 FontFamily -> "Kartika"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
f = "\!\(\*TagBox[SubscriptBox[\"y\", \"x\"],\n \
\"MathMLPresentationTag\",\nAutoDelete->True]\)";
```

or

```
f="\!\(x\_y\)"
```

[image]

```
StringQ[f]

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
super /: MakeBoxes[super[x_, y_], StandardForm] :=
   RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[ToString @ x, ToString @ y]}]

str = ToString[super[a, b], StandardForm]
```

[image]

```
str // Head
```

> String

```
str // FullForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Subscript["x","y"]` is not a string but you can convert it into one with `ToString`:

```
ToString[Subscript["x", "y"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now `StringQ@ToString[Subscript["x", "y"]]` is `True`

Comment: But have you seen the result? that is not desired.

Comment: well... if you care about the string I prefer that rather than \!\("x"\_"y"\)

Comment: ok, see ybeltukov's [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63635/how-to-join-two-strings-one-of-which-is-subscript/63639#63639). That is what I wanted. You were almost there, just what you need to add FormatType -> StandardForm as an option.