# How to print $\odot$ without it being cropped? (\[CircleDot] symbol)

Tags: export, bugs, fonts, linux, style

#### Preamble:

In some applications (astronomy, cosmology, etc), it is useful to measure things in solar quantities, say distances in $R_\odot$ or masses in $M_\odot$, and so on. Now and then I see Mathematica plots in respected papers, failing to display the symbol $\odot$ properly.

#### What happens:

In *Mathematica* the symbol is called `\[CircleDot]`. So, I write (it looks somewhat better in the cell):

```
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(\[CircleDot]\)]\)"] // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

As one can see, the symbol is cropped, and it is worrying.

#### Half of the solution:

Use `ScriptBaseLineShifts`, for example

```
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(\[CircleDot]\)]\)", 
  {ScriptBaselineShifts -> {-0.15}}] // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

However, this affects other indices, consider:

[image] (Method 1, cropped)

versus

[image] (Method 2, other indices affected).

#### Question:

How to make a nice looking $\mathrm{log_{10} M/M_{\odot}}$ in *Mathematica* in `Style` framework?

I couldn't find an analogue of `StringJoin` for `Style` expressions, and neither could I find a way to move indices around without using `Style` options (which one typically needs in the end anyway).

---

I am under Ubuntu 14, MMA 10, and was observed in older *Mathematica* version too.

Comment: @Öskå: My apologies, I believe it is standard in MMA 10, but might not be present in older versions.

Comment: @Öskå: Yes, that should work (even with Salmon), but how would it help to form a line with $M_\odot$ as part of it?

Comment: Applause, thank you!!! Would you care to combine your two last comments into an answer?

Comment: @Öskå: Yes, CircleDog would probably look more like a torus. Otherwise, please do, for it completely answers my question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the cropping.  Is it Linux-only?

Comment: Tested on three platforms.  Win: works.  Mac: works.  Linux: cropped.  Tagging as such.  @AlexeyBobrick Please do report the problem to WRI.

Comment: @Szabolcs, will do!

Comment: @Szabolcs: Was acknowledged at WRI and will hopefully get fixed one day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The circle is not cropped when used in a `Subscript`:

```
Subscript["M", "⊙"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus, by using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63639/1356) answer you can easily do:

```
str = "This is some text with a CircleDot: " <> 
  ToString[Subscript["M", "⊙"], FormatType -> StandardForm]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want some `Style`:

```
Style[str, Red, 20]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand the problem: I had no difficulty in getting the circle-dot subscript as a subscript on a character M, whether in an Input cell or an in-line math within a Text cell, simply by typing M Ctrl+_ Esc c. Esc Ctrl+space (where "+" indicates holding down two keys at once).

Comment: @murray, the problem is version-dependent - occurs only in linux, plus see the example line in the question. I used Typesetting->Subscript in the menu.